# How to create array within an array dynamically in JQueryMobile?

Tags: jquery, arrays, nested

I am trying to learn JQuerymobile and I am doing something like below just wanted to check if JQueryMobile support such things

```
function BooksCategory () {
        ID          = '';
        title       = '';
        imgURL      = '';
        description = '';
        bookCounts= '';
        Books       = [];
};
function Books () {
        categoryID           = '';
        bookID               = '';
        name                 = '';
        imgURL               = '';
        Cost         = '';
        termsandcondition    = '';
}
this.booksCategory = [];

ParseResponse()
{
     session.CatagoriesCount = response.BooksCategory.length;

     for (var k=0; k < session.CatagoriesCount; k++)
     {
       session.booksCategory[k]  = new BookCategory();

       var NoOfBooks = session.BooksCategory[k].bookCounts

       for (var j=0; j<NoOfBooks; j++)

        session.booksCategory[k].Books[j]   = new Books();  
    }
```

}

Why i am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of" for this statement

```
session.booksCategory[k].Books[j]   = new Books();
```

If this is not the correct way how do we create an array within array dynamically?

Regards
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
function BooksCategory () {
        ID          = '';
        title       = '';
        imgURL      = '';
        description = '';
        bookCounts= '';
        Books       = [];
};
```

to

```
function BooksCategory () {
        this.ID          = '';
        this.title       = '';
        this.imgURL      = '';
        this.description = '';
        this.bookCounts= '';
        this.Books       = [];
};
```

to have the Books property added to your instance of `BooksCategory` created using `new`. Without it, `session.booksCategory[k].Books` doesn't exist so you cant take its element `[0]`, hence your error.

The context `this` isn't implicit in javascript.

And of course do similarly for the other class.

**EDIT :**

and replace

```
var NoOfBooks = session.BooksCategory[k].bookCounts
```

by

```
var NoOfBooks = session.booksCategory[k].bookCounts;
```

Comment: Hi Dystroy thanks for reply.But that did't worked.Still Same error.

Comment: Are you sure `session.booksCategory` is created (for example with `session.booksCategory = [];` ) ? This isn't visible in your too partial code.

Comment: in a separate file i have created this this.BooksCatagory = [];and as shown in the code above i have initialized it as session.BooksCatagory[k] = new BookCategory();

Comment: this and session are the same ? Sure ?

Comment: OK, found it, and edited : you had written `session.BooksCategory` instead of `session.booksCategory`.

Comment: that's a typing mistake i did while posting this question.Sorry for trouble i am new to this forum but in my actual code i have done what you have suggested.still same error.

Comment: And where is defined "NoOfProducts" ? Without a proper code it's very hard to help you...